# Route to an id or class in a component in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular2-routing, angular4-router

I am new to Angular,in Angular whenever we create routing we define it for different components i.e we define `path` and `component` . Suppose I am on component `A` with path `/A` . Now suppose I want to go to a particular `id` in `A.component.html`. How to achieve this by routing( if possible defining a specific path for it like `/A#id`)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, What are you trying to achieve here and what do you mean by "go to a particular id in A.component.html" This is not clear.

Are you trying to route to /A#id from another component?

You should be able to pass your id / classname via angular routing as a string. You just need to read from the route params and perform your desired action.

In your app-routing ts

```
{ path: 'A/:id', component: AComponent },
```

In your AComponent .ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-component-a',
    templateUrl: './a.component.html'
})
export class AComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
        super();
     }

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        // This will get the param from your route
        this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
            if (params) {
                const idOrClassName= params['idOrClassName'];
                if (idOrClassName) {
                    // Perform action when idOrClassName is presented
                    return;
                } 

                // Perform action when idOrClassName is not presented   
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: ID should be id of any DOM element like a div

Comment: @AakashSingh What are you trying to achieve here? My answer should allow you to pass an id / classname as a string via angular routing. Your component can then read via route params and you can do whatever you want with that